# How to handle firebase auth errors with coroutines in kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have a suspend function that register an user with firebase auth.

I know that there are auth error codes, how can i get them inside the try cath?

I was thinking of using `e.message` and then translate them to my language but i dont know if that would be a good approach.

```
override suspend fun registerUserFirebase(email: String, password: String):Boolean {
    return try {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
        true
    } catch (e: Exception) {            
        if (e.message == "The email address is already in use by another account."){
            // Do stuff
        }
        false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special to do here with respect to coroutines. According to the API docs for [createUserWithEmailAndPassword()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) can yield different types of exceptions:

> Exceptions
>
> - FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException thrown if the password is not strong enough
> - FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException thrown if the email address is malformed
> - FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException thrown if there already exists an account with the given email address

Your code will need to [check the type of exception using `is`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html), or possibly using [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression), and determine what to do with each one on its own terms.