# Does Firebase Auth return an Error Code if authentification is not successful?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm building a login flow with Firebase Auth to authenticate users with email and password. While logging in, some things can go wrong: No account exists with the given email address, the password is wrong (...).

Does Firebase return any error code so I can add error handling? I only found the exception messages which I can use for error handling but is there any way to make this neater with error codes? I couldn't find anything in the official Firebase documentation.

```
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful) {
            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success")
        } 
    }.addOnFailureListener { exception: Exception ->
        when (exception.message) {
            "There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted." -> // Handle error
            "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password." ->// Handle error
            else -> // Handle error
        }
    }
```

Comment: According to this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124747/how-to-handle-firebase-auth-errors-with-coroutines-in-kotlin) you will have to deal with the exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Firebase return any error code so I can add error handling?

Sure it does. [FirebaseAuthException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException) class contains a method called [getErrorCode()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException#getErrorCode()) that:

> Returns an error code that may provide more information about the error.

Besides that, in the above documentation you'll also find two very useful sections:

> 1. Known Direct Subclasses:
>
> - [FirebaseAuthActionCodeException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthActionCodeException)
> - [FirebaseAuthEmailException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthEmailException)
> - [FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException)
> - [FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException)
> - [FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthMultiFactorException)
> - [FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException)
> - [FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException)
> - [FirebaseAuthWebException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWebException)

And:

> 2. Known Indirect Subclasses:
>
> - [FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException)

So you can always get a specific message according to the particular Exception that is thrown.

**Edit:**

> I was wondering is where to get a list of all error codes.

Firebase Auth doesn't provide a full list of errors. The linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37859582/how-to-catch-a-firebase-auth-specific-exceptions/38244409#38244409), might be considered a little old, as it is added on Jul 7 '16. Since then, Firebase Authentication SDK got some changes. If you are interested in error codes, you should check each type of Exception. For instance, a known direct subclass of [FirebaseAuthException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException), is called [FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException). Inside this class, you might see some error codes:

- ERROR_USER_DISABLED
- ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND
- ERROR_USER_TOKEN_EXPIRED
- ERROR_INVALID_USER_TOKEN.

So the best option that you have is to look inside each specific class.

This isn't available only in the case of authentication, it's available in the case of all the other Exception classes. For example, if we are talking about Cloud Firestore, the corresponding Exception is called [FirebaseFirestoreException](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException) and contains inside an [enum](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code) with error codes. Here are the values:

- ABORTED
- ALREADY_EXISTS
- CANCELLED
- DATA_LOSS
- DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
- FAILED_PRECONDITION
- INTERNAL
- INVALID_ARGUMENT
- NOT_FOUND
- OK
- OUT_OF_RANGE
- PERMISSION_DENIED
- RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
- UNAUTHENTICATED
- UNAVAILABLE
- UNIMPLEMENTED
- UNKNOWN

Comment: Hi @Alex, just had the time to try it out. It works, thanks a lot!
Last thing I was wondering is where to get a list of all error codes, I could not find them in the documentation but in this question (if anybody else needs it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38244409/10095327).
By the way, I would always upvote helpful answers but don't have the privilege to do so right now....

Comment: I have also added some error codes.  So please see my updated answer.

Comment: I have ;) Thank you for your help and the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If authentication fails, `Firebase` throws `Firebase Auth Error Code.`

You can find list of all the error codes and messages [Firebase Auth Error Codes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth#autherrorcodes.)
and take corresponding actions